# Aws Amplify (React PWA) - Clear Site Cache Data after changes

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, aws-amplify

I have a React PWA application on Aws Amplify, everytime there are repository updates, user is constrain to make this actions: 1. open chrome console, 2. Go to Application Tab, 3. Go to Storage 4. Clear Site Data 5. Refresh Application.

I noticed that every update main.js go in 404.

Is there a way for clear cache after new changes?

public/serviceWorker.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js').then(function (registration) {
          // Registration was successful
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function (err) {
          // registration failed :(
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved.
Cache issue is solved, alert doesn't appear.

- Removed js code from index.html
- Moved serviceWorker from public to src
- Added follow code to App.js;

  ```
    import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
    serviceWorker.register({
          onUpdate: registration => {
            alert('New version available!');
            if (registration && registration.waiting) {
              registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
            }
            window.location.reload();
          }
        });
  ```